# An equivalence statement for measure preserving invertible transformations

Tags: measure-theory, transformation, ergodic-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

I am trying to prove the claim in Remark 1.2.13. :
[image]
which I can if I can prove the two following which I don't know how to prove them:

1- If $T$ is a measurable transformation and B a measurable set then $T[B]$ is a measurable set?

2- If $T$ is an invertible measurable transformation $T^{-1}$ is a measurable transformation too?

If any one of the two questions wrong, then I would need another proof for the mentioned remark in the text.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: My question is to prove the claim of the remark 1.2.13 in the book ...

Answer (score 0):

In all of the Ergodic books I've seen, it is assumed that the definition of invertible means that the inverse is measurable.

In general, this need not be the case. Let $T(x)=2x\,\text{mod} 1$ and $X=[0,1)$ equipped with Lebesgue measure. This map is measure preserving, but it's inverse is not. To see that $T(x)$ is measure preserving, let $B\subset [0,1)$ be some measurable set, which can be assumed to be an interval of the form $(a,b)$. To see that $T(x)$ is a measure preserving transformation, we have the following calculation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\mu(T^{-1}\big{(}(a,b)\big{)}\\
&=\mu\Big{(}\big{(}\frac{a}{2}, \frac{b}{2}\big{)}\bigcup\big{(}\frac{a+1}{2}, \frac{b+1}{2}\big{)}\Big{)}\\
&=\mu((a,b))
\end{split}
\end{equation}
If the above calculation isn't obvious to you. Here are some concrete examples.

Suppose that $(a,b)=(0,1)$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
T^{-1}\big{(}(a,b)\big{)}&=T^{-1}\big{(}(0,1)\big{)}\\
&=\big{(}0,\frac{1}{2}\big{)}\cup\big{(}\frac{1}{2},1\big{)}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Additionally, suppose that $(a,b)=(0, \frac{1}{2})$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
T^{-1}\big{(}(a,b)\big{)}&=T^{-1}\big{(}(0,\frac{1}{2})\big{)}\\
&=\big{(}0,\frac{1}{4}\big{)}\cup\big{(}\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\big{)}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Hence, $T^{-1}\big{(}(a,b)\big{)}$ is a pair of two non-overlapping intervals, which preserves measure.

Conversely for the inverse, note that if $B=[0,\frac{1}{2})$, then ${(T^{-1})}^{-1}(B)=T(B)=[0,1)$, so the measures are different. Also note that the above example generalizes to $T(x)=nx\,\text{mod} 1$ for $n$ being any positive natural number.

Comment: Expanding maps are not bijections. If you extend the system to the solenoid it becomes a bijection, in which case the inverse is also measure preserving.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not true that bijective measurable maps are bimeasurable, see [Measurability of the inverse of a measurable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56022/169085). There it is shown that bijective measurable absolutely continuous maps are bimeasurable.

So let us let an **invertible measure preserving transformation** $f$ of a probability space $(X,\mu)$ stand for a bimeasurable bijection that preserves $\mu$ (which then implies the inverse also preserves $\mu$, as the Remark remarks).

Let me also mention that it is not uncommon to have all this be applicable $\mu$-almost everywhere, so that there are $\mu$-full measure sets $X_1,X_2\subseteq X$ such that $f:X_1\to X$ is measurable and measure preserving, $g:X_2\to X$ is measurable and measure preserving, $g\circ f = \operatorname{id}_{X_1}$, $f\circ g = \operatorname{id}_{X_2}$ (Here $g$ is $f^{-1}$ measure theoretically). A standard example is the isomorphism (in the category of measure-spaces and measure-preserving measurable maps) between the sequence space $F(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0},\{0,1\})$ and the standard Cantor set.

Comment: Does a measure preserving bijection have a measurable inverse? I think this is more relevant for OP's question.

Comment: One would need absolute continuity. For the backward map to be measure preserving the forward map ought to not create measure out of nothing.

Comment: Ok. Can you give an example of a measure preserving bijection that has no measurable inverse? I am having a hard time thinking of one!

Comment: Me too. I have some ideas but I'll hold onto them for now. It may very well be that your exclamation mark is well warranted.

Comment: So the q.2 is solved by assuming inverse to be measurable, and about q.1 I searched a lot but I think image of a measurable set under a measurable map need not be a measurable set (?) So the equivalence claimed in the remark of the book is valid?

Comment: q.1 and q.2 are equivalent. The remark is certainly false in general, but frequently, as both Alp Uzman and I commented, the dynamics literature defines invertible to mean that the inverse is measurable.

Comment: @AndrewMcMillan, ok, thanks!