# Measurable invariance of domain

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Invariance of domain theorem tells us that if a subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$  is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $V$ must be open itself.

Question: If a subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$  is homeomorphic to a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, must $V$  be Borel ?

Recall $Borel(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is defined to be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Homeomorphisms are continuous, and in particular measurable. If $f\colon V \to B$ is a homeomorphism with $B$ measurable, then so is $f^{-1}(B) = V$

Comment: @Didier I am not sure this argument is valid, am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: With respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebras, there is nothing more to say.

Comment: If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous map between topological spaces, then it is a measurable map between $X,Y$ as measurable spaces when both are equipped with Borel $\sigma-algebras$. Fine, I agree about that. (I will add a continuation due to word limit)

Comment: @Didier This argument just tells you $V$ is measurable as a subset of itself with respect to its own Borel-algebra, which is trivial. It says nothing about measurability of $V$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Thorgott Exactly, Confusing intrinsic vs. Extrinsic

Comment: So $f:V\rightarrow B$ is a measurable map between measurable spaces $V,B$ when equipped with their Borel algebras, This gives that $B=f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable subset of the measurable space $B$, but we still dont know if its a measrable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @Didier In other words, why cant one use your argument to deduce invariance of domain trivially

Comment: Yes, I agree there's something missing, my bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the question is yes. This is a consequence of the Lusin-Souslin Theorem (see e.g. Kechris' *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, p. 89 or https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56061/169085):

- If $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is Borel and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous such that $f|_B$ is injective, then the image $f(B)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is Borel.

We also have the measurable analog of the Invariance of Domain as stated on Wikipedia:

- If $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is Borel and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is Borel such that $f|_B$ is injective, then the image $f(B)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is Borel and $f|_B: B\to f(B)$ is a Borel isomorphism.

(In general one can replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a standard Borel space.)

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks.